# Spring Quartz Scheduler not working in ECS Cluster

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, quartz-scheduler, amazon-ecs

I am working on a scheduling application using **Spring Boot(2.2.7.RELEASE)**, **Quartz Scheduler(2.3.2)**. Application deployed in **AWS ECS Cluster and running in multiple EC2 instances** based on the load. I am using the **AWS RDS Mysql** database and created required quartz tables. I have used the following properties file for quartz.

**quartz.properties**-

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyClusteredScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 25
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = true
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000
```

Application Starting log -

```
2020-10-13 23:33:02.853  INFO 938 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.2 created.
2020-10-13 23:33:02.856  INFO 938 --- [           main] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : Using db table-based data access locking (synchronization).
2020-10-13 23:33:02.858  INFO 938 --- [           main] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : JobStoreCMT initialized.
2020-10-13 23:33:02.859  INFO 938 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'quartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
NOT STARTED.
Currently in standby mode.
Number of jobs executed: 0
Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
Using job-store 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore' 
- which supports persistence. and is not clustered.
```

Problem is multiple EC2 instances are picking up the same job at same time. Because of that getting the wrong result.

Can somebody please let me know what I am missing here? What I need to do here to make it work in the ECS cluster. Every time when the Spring application is getting started getting, it's showing the log message **is not clustered.**

Comment: From the log there's no evidence that quartz is seeing your properties file. Where is it in your deployment?

Comment: Application has been deployed in AWS ECS.

Comment: But where in the web app is that properties file? If you remove it and redeploy is anything different?

Comment: web app related settings are not required in Spring boot. I have resolved the issue and posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This's been resolved. I have added the following configuration details to the `application.properties` file and removed the `quartz.properties` file

```
spring.quartz.job-store-type = jdbc
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyClusteredScheduler
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = true
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000
```

Now the batch job is working fine in ECS and at a time only one job is running in the ECS cluster.